# Web Framework or app to display data in graphical format on webpage

Tags: mysql, web-applications, graph, interactive

I am looking for a web framework or any Web plugins that fetched data from database and display on a webpage in form of chart or Pie Diagrams.

For example I have an Excel reporting sheet build on C# that can extract data through MySql and displayed in excel sheet. But I wanted this data to be shown on an interactive webpage in graphs and pie diagrams.

Comment: You can use ASP.NET/ Php for this purpose

Comment: But that requires lot of coding and integration. Is there something which is quick and easy to built with scaffolding. Where I dont have to write much code and just feed my sql data and show up on screen with jquery pie chats

Comment: Are you after a solution client or server side? If you can output the data in the correct format, [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) might be one viable solution.